# On startup: ImportError: No module named ropevim

Tags: filetype-python

When starting `nvim`, my `:messages` contains:

> ```
> Error detected while processing function LoadRope[4]..provider#python#Call:
> line   18:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: No module named ropevim
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: No module named ropevim
> ```

- `ropevim` is installed by: `NeoBundleLazy 'python-rope/ropevim', { 'on_ft': 'python' }`
- `:checkhealth` is all green
- `pip install --user --upgrade ropevim` is fully satisfied
- `py3 print(ropevim.__dict__)` produces a bunch of `rope`-y output

What does `ropevim` need to be happy?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `ropevim` is a Python 2 animal:

```
pip2 install --user ropevim
```